# Power & Reset in momentary switch in analog circuit

Tags: switches, 555, reset

So I am designing a circuit and wanted to implement both power and reset in one momentary switch. What I mean is, if the switch is pressed, it sends a reset signal (4.5v), but if it is held for *x* seconds, it powers on/off. I figure I might need a 555 timer.
How to do this?

**EDIT:** Some specifics:

One press when the circuit is off turns it on. It is to reset an IC (so HIGH at 4.5v).

Comment: And why are you not just using a regular on/off switch? There's something peculiar about your application.

Comment: I just wanted it this way

Comment: Um... so how is it supposed to reset if it just powered off... Normally this function works the other way around. A short press resets, hold in for Xs shuts her down. BTW Off with this type of control is not really off either.

Comment: I know, its just kinda in standby

Comment: You will get much better answers if you divulge all the relevant information. Otherwise you will waste a lot of people's time.

Comment: By reset do you mean a micro... and can the micro watch the switch or do you want the thing to power out even if the micro has left the building...? I am guessing yes to the latter.

Comment: No its to reset an ic

Comment: Final question.... How do you want to power up again... One more press? BTW.. Hit edit below your question and add all these specifics to the question.... discussions tend to disappear.

Comment: Yes, pressing again

Comment: so, can the long press first send the reset and later power off? Anyway, this is getting rather specific, so a simple 40-70ct microcontroller is almost certainly the cheapest and most flexible way to go, short of designing relatively complex analog circuitry.

Comment: ok i'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discrete analog circuit could be something like this...

Power would always be available at SOURCE and is switched via the P-MOSFET M1 to the POWER_OUT line.

Initially all transistors are off.

The P-MOSFET is gated by an N-MOSFET, M3. This MOSFET is gated either by the momentary switch to SOURCE, or via the output from the P-MOSFET. As such when you press the button M3 turns on, which then turns on M1, which then keeps M3 turned on when the switch is released.

SW1 also charges C2 to hold the RESET line high until the button is released, at that point reset will decay as C2 is discharges through R5.

Further, holding down SW1 will cause C1 to charge through resistor R1. When the voltage at the top of C1 rises above the gate threshold of  N-MOSFET M2, the latter will turn on and pull the gate of M3 low, turning off the P-MOSFET which will stay turned off when the button is released. C1 will then discharge through D4 and R6 during which time you would not be able to power up again.

Briefly pressing the button again while it is powered up will simply recharge the reset capacitor.

Note the circuit itself uses zero current, other than leakage, when the button is not being held in.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwjvca.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wouldn't some capacitance on Power_out turn M3 back on after SW1 is released? (For example if he has ~100uF on whatever he is powering)

Comment: @WesleyLee if the button is not held in long enough it might. But the time constant on R1 C1 is so long the LOAD discharge should be long gone. IF it's a high cap low R load though some additional discharge here would be prudent.

Comment: Hmm, although a series diode would easily solve that.. If OP can tolerate the V drop..

Comment: @WesleyLee ya or a diode and R up from M2 to the load. Which is basically R3 D2 anyway

Comment: Oh, true.. I didn't take the R1/C1 delay into account.

Comment: @WesleyLee Adding another M2 in parallel to dump the load could be an option too if it turned out to be a problem.